# Nuxt.js application deployed on Google Cloud Run returns 502 error

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, google-cloud-run

I have a Nuxt.js application that works perfectly when I run it locally using Docker, but when I deploy it to Google Cloud Run, I get a 502 error. The application is served by Nginx and managed by Supervisor.

Here are the relevant parts of my `nginx.conf` and `supervisord.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    error_log /dev/stdout info;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000; # Django
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; # Nuxt
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true


[program:app-uwsgi]
command = /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini django_app.uwsgi.ini
directory=/app/django_app
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:nuxt]
command=npm run start
directory=/app/nuxt-app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0


[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

And here is the error message I get from the Cloud Run logs:

```
2023/12/23 14:45:56 [error] 5#5: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 169.254.169.126, server: , request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api", host: "nuxt-django-cr7u6vkd4q-an.a.run.app"
2023-12-23 23:45:56.462 JST
169.254.169.126 - - [23/Dec/2023:14:45:56 +0000] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-12-23 23:45:56.463 JST
2023/12/23 14:45:56 [info] 5#5: *6 client 169.254.169.126 closed keepalive connection
2023-12-23 23:46:52.423 JST
2023-12-23 14:46:52,423 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2023-12-23 23:46:52.423 JST
2023-12-23 14:46:52,423 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2023-12-23 23:46:52.423 JST
2023-12-23 14:46:52,423 INFO waiting for nginx, nuxt to die
2023-12-23 23:46:52.424 JST
2023-12-23 14:46:52,423 INFO waiting for nginx, nuxt to die
2023-12-23 23:46:53.203 JST
 ╭───────────────────────────────────Preview Mode─────────────────────────────────────╮
2023-12-23 23:46:53.203 JST
 │                                                                                    │
2023-12-23 23:46:53.203 JST
 │  You are running Nuxt production build in preview mode.                            │
2023-12-23 23:46:53.203 JST
 │  For production deployments, please directly use node ./server/index.mjs command.  │
2023-12-23 23:46:53.203 JST
 │                                                                                    │
2023-12-23 23:46:53.203 JST
 │  Node.js:           v18.13.0                                                       │
2023-12-23 23:46:53.203 JST
 │  Nitro Preset:      node-server                                                    │
2023-12-23 23:46:53.203 JST
 │  Working directory: .output                                                        │
2023-12-23 23:46:53.203 JST
 │                                                                                    │
2023-12-23 23:46:53.203 JST
 ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
2023-12-23 23:46:53.203 JST
2023-12-23 14:46:53,203 WARN stopped: nuxt (terminated by SIGTERM)
2023-12-23 23:46:53.210 JST
2023-12-23 14:46:53,210 INFO stopped: nginx (exit status 0)
2023-12-23 23:47:39.772 JST
GET5021.17 KB5 msChrome 120 https://nuxt-django-cr7u6vkd4q-an.a.run.app/api 
2023-12-23 23:47:39.783 JST
2023/12/23 14:47:39 [error] 5#5: *8 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 169.254.169.126, server: , request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api", host: "nuxt-django-cr7u6vkd4q-an.a.run.app"
2023-12-23 23:47:39.783 JST
169.254.169.126 - - [23/Dec/2023:14:47:39 +0000] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-12-23 23:47:39.786 JST
2023/12/23 14:47:39 [info] 5#5: *8 client 169.254.169.126 closed keepalive connection
2023-12-23 23:47:41.042 JST
GET5021.17 KB6 msChrome 120 https://nuxt-django-cr7u6vkd4q-an.a.run.app/api 
2023-12-23 23:47:41.049 JST
2023/12/23 14:47:41 [error] 4#4: *10 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 169.254.169.126, server: , request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api", host: "nuxt-django-cr7u6vkd4q-an.a.run.app"
2023-12-23 23:47:41.049 JST
169.254.169.126 - - [23/Dec/2023:14:47:41 +0000] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-12-23 23:47:41.051 JST
2023/12/23 14:47:45 [info] 4#4: *14 client 169.254.169.126 closed keepalive connection
2023-12-23 23:47:45.947 JST
> start
2023-12-23 23:47:45.947 JST
> nuxt start
2023-12-23 23:47:47.772 JST
GET5021.17 KB4 msChrome 120 https://nuxt-django-cr7u6vkd4q-an.a.run.app/ 
2023-12-23 23:47:47.777 JST
2023/12/23 14:47:47 [error] 5#5: *16 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 169.254.169.126, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "nuxt-django-cr7u6vkd4q-an.a.run.app"
2023-12-23 23:47:47.777 JST
169.254.169.126 - - [23/Dec/2023:14:47:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-12-23 23:47:47.779 JST
2023/12/23 14:47:47 [info] 5#5: *16 client 169.254.169.126 closed keepalive connection
2023-12-23 23:47:50.735 JST
GET5021.17 KB3 msChrome 120 https://nuxt-django-cr7u6vkd4q-an.a.run.app/api 
2023-12-23 23:47:50.739 JST
2023/12/23 14:47:50 [error] 4#4: *18 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 169.254.169.126, server: , request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api", host: "nuxt-django-cr7u6vkd4q-an.a.run.app"
2023-12-23 23:47:50.739 JST
169.254.169.126 - - [23/Dec/2023:14:47:50 +0000] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-12-23 23:47:50.741 JST
2023/12/23 14:47:50 [info] 4#4: *18 client 169.254.169.126 closed keepalive connection
```

I've checked the Nuxt.js and Nginx configurations, and they seem to be correct. I've also made sure that the Nuxt.js server is listening on the correct port.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm using Cloud Run's default port 8080.
I executed the following command inside the container and received a successful response. `curl http://localhost:3000`